# How can I have the "Generate Signed APK" tool in Android Studio use the info in keystore.properties?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I followed [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#secure-key) to create a `keystore.properties` file and use have it used in the app `build.gradle` for my Android Studio project. This has allowed me to not have to enter the signing credentials into the gradle file, and to build and run a release version of the app without having to manually enter the credentials. However, when I select "Generate Signed APK...", I still need to enter the credentials. Is it possible to have this tool just use the information in `keystore.properties`?

Comment: Why do you have to select "Generate Signed APK..." ? Just use ./gradlew assembleRelease

Comment: Because I think this is something I should be able to do without leaving Android Studio. Also because that command requires installing the JDK, which I'd rather not do if I don't have to.

Comment: But you can run gradle tasks inside Android Studio. JDK is also required to compile Android...

Comment: Clearly JDK is not required because I can compile my Android Studio project into build and release APKs without JDK being installed. It only asks me to install it when I run the command in Android Studio's terminal or a separate terminal. You're right though that Android Studio has a terminal, I forgot about that.

Comment: A copy of the latest OpenJDK comes bundled with Android Studio 2.2 and higher. Without JDK you can't compile java classes.

Comment: If that's the case they my copy of OpenJDK must be inaccessible from the terminal, because I get the message "No Java runtime present, requesting install." when I run `./gradlew assembleRelease` either on Android Studio's terminal or a separate one.